# Another way to write if statements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I was checking the code in a library and I found this little piece:

```
if (typeof options === 'function') (callback = options), (options = {});
```

Is this just another way of writing

```
if (typeof options == 'function) {
  callback = options;
  options = {};
}
```

?

It's just that I've never seen an `if` statement declared like this and wondered if this is accepted, maybe, only in Javascript?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: The body of an `if` statement has to be a single statement (using a *block statement* (`{...}`) allows you to write multiple statements). In this case it is an *expression statement*. `(callback = options), (options = {})` is a single expression, using the [comma](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) operators. It's not a special version of the `if` statement, it's just (ab)using the language constructs.

Comment: Just keep the style like in the latter example, the first snippet is not readable, though it's valid JS.

Comment: It's correct, as in, *it works*, but I'd also call that a terrible abuse bordering on needless obfuscation.